# Jframe becomes empty on adding image

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, imageicon

I need to display an image from my pc file system. The image is stored at -
**C:\Users\Akshay\Desktop\allfiles**

The relevant code is (scroll to right) :

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setExtendedState( frame.getExtendedState()|JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JLabel title = new JLabel("Image : ");
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Akshay\\Desktop\\allfiles\\sampleposter.jpg"); //line #1 
    JLabel l = new JLabel("");
    l.setIcon(image); // line #2
    frame.add(title);
    frame.add(l);
```

Following is the output. I am getting an **empty frame** instead of two jlabels.

[image]

On commenting line #2 in the code i.e. -

```
l.setIcon(image);
```

I get the same output instead of two simple `JLabels`

On commenting both line #1 and line #2 , I am getting the two labels (one empty) as shown below.

[image]

How do I display the image properly with the other label? What could be the problem here?

Comment: What does `System.out.println(new File().exists("C:\\Users\\Akshay\\Desktop\\allfiles\\sampleposter.jpg"));` print? You've also set `BorderLayout.CENTER` (default value) for both you `JLabels`.

Comment: You're adding components *after* the `JFrame` has been realized (i.e. made visible). You should add those components before you do that, otherwise you'll need to `revalidate`/`validate` and issue a `repaint` on the container.

Comment: @Xeon That returns true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- you added JLabel title = new JLabel("Image : "); to the already visible Swing GUI, after setVisible(true); was called,
- move code lines creating JLabel with ImageIcon before frame.setVisible(true);
- move code line frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); before frame.setVisible(true);

Comment: +1, Nice catch with setting the layout manager before realizing the container.